# how to adjust space between buttons equally using AutoLayout

Tags: autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a main screen with three button vertically aligned. I want adopt my app for 4" screen. so I want to adjust space between buttons equally to fill the screen. 
see the below images:
how can I accomplish that using AutoLayout?

the green area keeps its size.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please consider marking one of these answers as "accepted".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ***Edit:*** Apple now favors the use of stack views for this purpose. See [this WWDC 2013 video for OS X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013-213/) and [this iOS one from WWDC 2015](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=218)

<s>The [Apple approved way of doing this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutbyExample/AutoLayoutbyExample.html) (look for section titled "Creating Equal Spacing Between Views")</s> is to insert hidden views between each of your buttons and set those views' heights to be equal.

See [my answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21221113/90413) for some discussion on why this approach makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Add each button in view with clearColor for background, align by centerY and CenterX by it subview. setup Constraints like:

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[box][viewForButton1][viewForButton2][viewForButton3]|" options:nil metrics:0 views:viewDic]];
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[viewForButton1]|" options:nil metrics:0 views:viewDic]];
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[viewForButton2]|" options:nil metrics:0 views:viewDic]];
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[viewForButton3]|" options:nil metrics:0 views:viewDic]];
```